# Will Mac Mini i5 OSX 10.7.5 Boot in 64 Bit Mode

Tags: macos, mac-mini, 64-bit, adobe-lightroom

Considering buying a mid 2011 Mini i5 OSX 10.7.5 (16GB) to run Lightroom 6/CC and Photoshop CC.  They require 64 bit systems.  My Air (4GB) doesn't have enough RAM to run efficiently. Will the Mini boot in 64 bit as is, will I need to hold down 6 + 4 during start up, or do I need to upgrade to Yosemite?

Comment: Everything from a Core 2 Duo upwards is 64bit, so you can certainly download the 64bit no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this simple command in Terminal it will show you

```
system_profiler
```

Even more direct method is to use the:

```
sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable
```

It will return 1=Yes, or 0 = no